# Why state is showing data while it is empty array initially in redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice  } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
    loading:false,
    error:null,
    data:[]
}

export const loadFormDetails = createAsyncThunk("/form/details", async(userId)=>{
    const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/form/formdetails/${userId}`).then((response)=>response.json())
    console.log(response);
    return response
})

const homepageSlice = createSlice({
    name:"homepage",
    initialState,
    reducers:{},
    extraReducers:{
        [loadFormDetails.pending]:(state, action)=>{
            state.loading=true
        },
        [loadFormDetails.fulfilled]:(state, action)=>{
            // console.log(action.payload)
            state.loading=false
            state.data=action.payload
        },
        [loadFormDetails.rejected]:(state, action)=>{
            state.error=true
        }
    }
})

export default homepageSlice.reducer
```

here clearly it is written that initially the data will be empty and after fetching the data empty array will be replaced by some data but I dont know why it is taking `success:false` as initial data in data field, because of that I can not perform map method on properly.
[image]

Homepage.jsx here i am calling the reducer function

```
import React from 'react'
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import Form from './Form'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import Modal from './Modal'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { loadFormDetails } from '../features/homepageSlice'
import FormBody from './FormBody'
import FormSubmit from './FormSubmit'
import SubmissionNumber from './SubmissionNumber'
import SubmitDetails from './SubmitDetails'

const Homepage = () => {
  const userdetails = useSelector((store) => store.userlogin)
  const homepageDetails = useSelector((store) => store.homepageDetails)
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("userid")) {
      navigate("/login")
    }
}, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadFormDetails(localStorage.getItem("userid")))
  }, [])


  const modal = useSelector((store) => store.modal.modal)
  return (
    <div>
      {
        modal && <Modal />
      }
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path='' element={<FormBody />} />
        <Route path='create' element={<Form />} />
        <Route path="form/:formid/submission" element={<FormSubmit />} />
        <Route path="submission/:formid" element={<SubmissionNumber />} />
        <Route path="values/:submissionid" element={<SubmitDetails />} />
      </Routes>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Homepage
```

Formbody.jsx here i am accessing the data

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import FormItem from './FormItem'


const FormBody = () => {
    const {data, loading} = useSelector((store) => store.homepageDetails)
    console.log(data);

    
    if (loading) {
        return (
            <div>Loading</div>
        )
    }
    return (
        <div className=' flex flex-wrap'>
            {
                 data.map((formdetail, index) => {
                    return (

                        <FormItem {...formdetail} />

                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default FormBody
```

result of `console.log(response)`

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0
: 
{_id: '634d00f919d2e7c1614c17be', formname: 'dhiran', formFields: Array(3), submissionCount: 1, fieldCount: 3}
1
: 
{_id: '634d0ae03f31b17e7208ae7e', formname: 'hello', formFields: Array(3), submissionCount: 2, fieldCount: 3}
2
: 
{_id: '6352d55197b9bb7ff932c215', formname: 'nepal', formFields: Array(4), submissionCount: 1, fieldCount: 4}
```

Comment: Post the code where you are using this slice.

Comment: Also post the result of your `console.log(response);`

Comment: @possum I have updated the code and added the response also

Comment: I ran a reduced version of your code without problems, so I'm not sure what's going on.  In your position, I would start building a minimal version and work your way back up to your implementation to reveal the issue.